# normalize 3d point data to origin (c++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, normalization

I have a `<vector<vector<3dPoint>>` filled with data such that `(x,y,z) >= 0`.  How do I normalize this data with the origin?  Best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean something else than normalizing each 3dPoint?

Comment: @bolov I'd like the points to be centered at the origin.  Some points negative, some points positive, etc.

Comment: Be careful with the terms you use. Normalization is a well defined operations on points (vectors) and it is not what you want.[Edit] the question to make it clear what you want.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow if all the coordinates are non-negative, then how do you want some of them to suddenly become negative?

Answer (score 1):

get the magnitude of each vector

`float n  =sqrt((x* x) + (y* y) + (z* z));`

and then

```
x = x/n; 
y = y/n; 
z = z/n;
```

Comment: if `3dPoint` is a structure like `struct 3dPoint{ float x; float y; float z } 3dPoint;` then `float x = 3dPoint.x ;` etc....